# Create tensor from list of dictionaries of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a pipeline that loads data from a TFRecord and after pre-processing gives a FlatMapDataset -- a list with a feature dictionary for every observation in my data (dimensions of nrow x features). I would like to flatten this into one large tensor. Can this be done?

So far I've only managed to output a MapDataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_decision_forests as tfdf 

# Download the dataset
!wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/palmer_penguins/penguins.csv -O /tmp/penguins.csv

# Load a dataset into a Pandas Dataframe.
dataset_df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/penguins.csv")

# Predictor variables
predictors = ["bill_length_mm", "bill_depth_mm", "flipper_length_mm", "body_mass_g"]

# Filter dataset to predictors of interest
dataset_df = dataset_df.loc[:, predictors]

# Create FlatMapDataset
ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(dataset_df)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))

# Flatten
ds_flat = ds.map(lambda elem: tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.nest.flatten(elem)))
```

I can accomplish my goal by looping over each element of the FlatMapDataset, but in reality my dataset is much larger than this example so this approach is too inefficient:

```
# Alternative:
list_of_tensors = []
for element in ds:
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.nest.flatten(element))
    list_of_tensors.append(tensor)
ds_as_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_of_tensors)
```

Desired output:

```
print(ds_as_tensor)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(344, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[  18.7,   39.1, 3750. ,  181. ],
       [  17.4,   39.5, 3800. ,  186. ],
       [  18. ,   40.3, 3250. ,  195. ],
       ...,
       [  18.2,   49.6, 3775. ,  193. ],
       [  19. ,   50.8, 4100. ,  210. ],
       [  18.7,   50.2, 3775. ,  198. ]])>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid for loops, you can at first batch the whole dataset to single batch and then iterate over this dataset (which has only one element):

```py
n_values = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(ds).numpy()
ds_batched = ds.batch(n_values)
ds_as_tensor = tf.constant(next(ds_batched.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

This seems to be the most time efficient option, almost 10-times faster than your solution (measured using [%timeit](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) magic function in jupyter notebook on my machine):

```py
%%timeit
n_values = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(ds).numpy()
ds_batched = ds.batch(n_values)
ds_as_tensor = tf.constant(next(ds_batched.as_numpy_iterator()))

>>> 7.93 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%%timeit
list_of_tensors = []
for element in ds:
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.nest.flatten(element))
    list_of_tensors.append(tensor)
ds_as_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_of_tensors)

>>> 76.9 ms ± 913 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If for any reason the first solution does not work, this one-liner seems to be quite efficient as well:

```py
%%timeit
ds_as_tensor = tf.constant([x for x in ds.as_numpy_iterator()])

>>> 27.2 ms ± 571 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I just wanted to point out to 2 small edits needed to make it work, in case others view this. 1) I was given a value of -2 for `n_values` -- you cannot compute cardinality from a TFRecord (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26966). Fortunately, I know the size of my data so I specified it directly, but I have could also have ran `sum(1 for _ in ds_flat)` to get `n_values`. 2) In your solutions, when you refer to `ds` it is actually my `ds_flat` object that is being referenced.